# My "var" doesn't work well

Tags: r

all. I have a trouble about one of the most basic. Here is the problem;

```
> mean(1:10)
[1] 5.5

>sd(1:10)
[1] 3.02765

> var(1:10)
 [1] 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

> x<-data.frame(first=c(1,2),second=c(3,4))

> mean(x$first)
[1] 1.5

> sd(x$first)
[1] 0.7071068

> var(x$first)
[1] 0 0

> var(x)
     first second
[1,]     0      0
[2,]     0      0
```

Why R calculate variance for each cell? This is really inconvenient. I reinstalled R, but it did not fix the problem. 
Could you give me your advises?Please

Thank you.
Kyosuke

Comment: What is the output of `find('var')`? It looks as if you have redefined `var` (or have another definition of `var` in the search tree prior to `package:ststs)

Comment: I would say it is not working well at all!

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
ls(pattern='var')
rm(var)
```

It will get rid of the extraneous (and incorrect) function you have defined and is hanging around in the .Rdata image that is being loaded  automatically. (It's a hidden file and it would not be wiped out by reinstalling.) If you define a function with the same name as a built-in function like `var`, it will mask the original function.

Answer (score 0):

Use `apply` when you want to apply a function to either rows or cols

```
> apply(x, 2, var)
 first second 
   0.5    0.5
```

Alternatively you can use `sapply(x, var)` if `x` is a data.frame

`var(x$first)` worked well for me

```
> var(x$first)
[1] 0.5
```

You can also use `colVars` function from `matrixStats` package

```
> #install.packages("matrixStats")
> library(matrixStats)
> colVars(x)
 first second 
   0.5    0.5
```

See `?matrixStats` for further details.

Answer (score 0):

Your result looks strange. For your data var(x) and cov(x) should give:

```
       first second
first    0.5    0.5
second   0.5    0.5
```